# Is there a simple way to recover accidentally deleted records in Azure SQL?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have an azure sql database and I need to recover data (rows) that were accidentally deleted by a user a few months ago but were only noticed now. The Point in Time restore's don't go that far back unfortunately.

There doesn't seem to be a clear way to do this, everything I've found so far is for mssql instances which this isn't.

I am not an expert at azure or mssql so I would appreciate dumbed down answers if there possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can restore to a point in time to another (new) database, the default backup retention is 7 days which will hopefully be enough to find your missing data.

[This blog post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-sql-database-point-in-time-restore/) takes you through the necessary steps.

Depending on how much and how complex the missing data is there are a few ways to get the data back, eg anything from manually recreating the data, exporting via query explorer in the portal from the restored database and creating a script from the export locally, using a tool like visual studio data compare, SSMS, etc.

### Edit

So to answer your edit, depending on the recovery model configured for SQL Server, point in time restore is supported as long as you have access to the transaction log for the time in question, this means either in the live logs or a backup of them. Transaction logs are truncated after being backed up hence if you have backups but not for the time you need then sadly you cannot get access to the lost data. Azure SQL databases are managed for you in full recovery mode with backups configured.

You can configure [long term retention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/long-term-retention-overview) in Azure SQL as well as a number of days of log backups, this way if your log backups don't go back far enough you at least have a full backup for whatever points in time you configure.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, I've updated the question with a bit more detail. Essentially, it was deleted a few months ago, and only noticed this week when they ran a report and the data was missing.

Is there a way to recover something that far back?

Comment: @Bernard If this answer helped you, please click the green checkmark to mark this as an answer and as resolved.